# exposed roots pine tree

Tags: roots

I have a pine tree with exposed roots. I have read not to cover the roots, but can I safely put soil on the side of the roots to make a level ground for mowing purposes. I try to avoid the roots but i do forget about them and do not want to harm them

Comment: A photo is always best

Comment: Did exposure develop over years or quickly during some construction ?

Answer (score 1):

Well established trees do not like sudden changes in the grade of the soil around their roots.  [Roots absorb oxygen](https://cid-inc.com/blog/root-respiration-importance-and-applications/) [from the air](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=730) and the [active area](https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1111/j.1469-8137.1971.tb02513.x) for this is the [top few inches of soil](https://www.scielo.org.mx/scielo.php?pid=S2007-09342020000400931&script=sci_arttext_plus&tlng=en).  If you cover it then they cannot absorb oxygen.

You can do any of these:

- top dress with a half inch of compost or soil twice a year.  A few years of this will raise the grade slowly
- remove the grass and mulch around the roots. Grass is competing with the tree for water and nutrients so there is a double bonus of less to mow and more for the tree

Comment: I went searching for info on roots absorbing oxygen. I found a lot of claims and counter claims, but nobody with tests and actual data.

Comment: @BobaFit I found plenty of references and have added them to the answer